# Как сложить значения объектов в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Как сложить значения объектов массива такого вида:

```
[{
  number: 3,
},
{
  number: 10,
},
{
  number: 13
}]
```

Чтобы в на выходе получить 26.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var d = [
  { number: 3 },
  { number: 10 },
  { number: 13 }
];

console.log(d.reduce((s, i) => s = s + i.number, 0));
```

Comment: Отлично, все работает. Если вас не затруднит, могли бы вы объяснить, как сработал данный метод?

Answer (score 2):

Хотел вам объяснить как работает пример, который вам предоставил в качестве ответа: [Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176262/igor). Ответ не меняйте, ибо я просто для ясности пишу. Сильно углубляться не буду, но оставлю ссылки, которые вам помогу понять. Пытайтесь сами искать про эти методы, и разбираться как они работают. Все есть в открытом доступе и очень наглядно расписано.

- [reduce/reduceRight](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration#reduce-reduceright)
- [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let arr = [
  { number: 3 },
  { number: 10 },
  { number: 13 }
];

let initialValue = 0;

//Метод reduce применяет функцию callback по очереди к каждому элементу массива слева направо, сохраняя при этом промежуточный результат.
//Так как мы передаем агрумент initialValue (0), то accumulator будет в начале равен initialValue. Если не передавать initialValue, то при первом запуске accumulator будет равен: { number: 3 }.

let result = arr.reduce(function callback(accumulator, currentValue) {
  console.log(`accumulator равен: ${accumulator}, а currentValue равен: ${currentValue}`);
  return accumulator = accumulator + currentValue.number;
}, initialValue);

console.log(`result равен: ${result}`);
```